# Using Perforce API to test user authentication?

Tags: c#, authentication, perforce

I would like to, using the p4 api, automate the testing of whether a user has access to specific source code or not.  All users have a username/password, but not all user have the status of admin.  Is there a way I can test for admin status using only the username?

I realize that I could attempt to access a file and, if an error is thrown, I can assume that the user is not an admin.  If there is a better or more direct way to do this, however, I would like to know!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for 'p4 protects -u username': http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/protects.html#1040665

Comment: Thanks!  I believe this is equivalent to the method GetProtectionTable in the api, which looks to be what I need.  However, it is saying that I don't have permission to use this method, so I will work on getting permission.  Thanks for the guidance.